# AthenaJDBC conflicting dependencies

Tags: dependencies, aws-sdk, amazon-athena

The [AthenaJDBC library](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html) is a fat jar. It has its dependencies embedded with it. Some of these dependencies overlap with the AWS S3 library and are only partially included.

If I exclude dependencies from S3 jar, I get compilation errors relating to classes not found.

```
libraryDependencies ++= {
  List(
    ...
    "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.179" excludeAll (
      ExclusionRule(name = "ion-java"),
      ExclusionRule(name = "aws-java-sdk-core")
    ),
    "com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc" % "AthenaJDBC41" % "1.0.1-atlassian-hosted"
  )
}
```

Leads to errors like:

```
Class com.amazonaws.SdkClientException not found - continuing with a stub.
...
```

But if I don't, I am unable to assemble my own app:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
/Users/jem/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.179.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.class
/Users/jem/.ivy2/cache/com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc/AthenaJDBC41/jars/AthenaJDBC41-1.0.1-atlassian-hosted.jar:com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.class
...
```

As far as I can see, my only way forward is to

1. Find a non-fat version of AthenaJDBC - but I haven't been able to find it; or
2. Find what version of AWS core libs are bundled in AthenaJDBC, so I can downgrade to that dependency for the S3 lib. I've inspected the AthenaJDBC jar, but can't discern which version of AWS libs it has bundled.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you find any solution?

Comment: No. I can't quite recall, but I think I found some other approach not involving Athena. Sorry.